# Have to compile several times with XCode

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction

I'm programming an audio app in XCode 3.2.6, using C++. Often, after making changes or additions to the code, I have to compile 3 or 4 times before the program runs ok. Each time, it compiles with no compiler errors, but either the sound glitches, or I get random runtime errors, or it just crashes. If I compile 3 or 4 times without making any changes to the code, it then runs fine, and i never run into any problems (until I make more changes to the code later on). This doesn't happen every time I make changes or additions, but often enough to make me want to throw my computer out the window.

Anyone else experience this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is someone modifying your code while your back is turned? Not an uncommon programming prank...

Comment: Ha. Unless my cat is a devious little genius, no.

Comment: That's your problem right there! This is the first time I've heard "cat" and "devious little genius" and *"unless"* in the same sentence. Usually it is *"because"*

Answer (score 0):

Its not a compiler fault, but a fault in the code you are compiling.

Any program that sometimes runs OK and sometimes does not is using uninitialised store. These initialised variables are either used as memory references or array subscripts in parts of the code where runtime bound checking is not active. This is frequently a problem in C and also occurs in C++.

A you programmed the Audio app, the fault will be in you code. When it fails you need to do detailed debugging and then you will find the uninitialised store.

Any experienced programmer should be aware what are the causes and cures of random faults in programs.